How to use thicker backslash with listings verbatims?

As seen above, \textbackslash is thinner than what we get by default. I literate \ because I want to get flexibility to adjust all special characters of interest
My MWE
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{listings}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\lstdefinestyle{LaTeX-inline}{
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
literate=
*{{\\}}{{\textbackslash{}}}{1},
}

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}{@{}l X[l, t]@{}}
    
    with \verb|\textbackslash|
    & \lstinline[style=LaTeX-inline]|\|
    \\
    
    \verb|listings| default with \verb|\ttfamily\footnotesize|
    & \lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize]|\|
    \\
    
\end{NiceTabularX}

\end{document}


Does it need to be a textbackslash? literate= *{{\\}}{{\symbol{92}}}{1}, }

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. May you conver your comment to an answer?

@Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Accepting the suggested duplicate would make more sense. It shows a lot more different solutions.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz \symbol{92} is much less strange than \symbol{`\\}, so I think at least you must edit the suggested duplicate answer

@Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Some people would argue that \symbol{\\}` is more performant.
